# how to access all the cameras of samsung device using camerax/camera2?

Tags: android, camera

I have observed that in device camera app, when we zoom to 2.0 or 3.0 in samsung devices, it switches lens to high focal length one. Since I wanted to do same in my app as well, first I tried to check all the cameras i can access through CameraX/Camera2 API. I am already using wide angle lens and default lens in my app. And using below code all I could see is just these 2 cameras printed. Is it possible to use high focal length camera of Samsung?

```
val backCameras = cameraInfos.filterIsInstance<Camera2CameraInfoImpl>()
                .filter {
                    val pixelWidth = it.cameraCharacteristicsCompat.get(
                        CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PIXEL_ARRAY_SIZE
                    )?.width ?: 0
                    it.lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK && pixelWidth >= 2000 
                }
for (cam in backCameras) {
                Logger.debug("cam test", "-----${cam.camera2CameraInfo.cameraId}")
                cam.camera2CameraInfo.getCameraCharacteristic(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS)
                    ?.iterator()?.forEach {
                    Logger.debug("cam test", "-----${it}")
                }
            }
```